# Cypress .intercept() not working in CircleCI, works locally

Tags: cypress, circleci

I have a set of tests running fine locally, but when they're running inside of a CircleCI build, the intercept command doesn't work as intended. Checking the Cypress recording shows that no request is ever made.

**Test Code:**

```
before( () => {
   cy.intercept( 'GET', '**wp-json/wp/v2/pages?context=edit&status%5B0%5D=publish**' ).as( 'getPages' );
   cy.intercept( 'GET', '**wp-json/wp/v2/posts?context=edit&status%5B0%5D=publish**' ).as( 'getPosts' );

   openComplementaryArea( 'Site contents' );

   // Make sure our data has loaded.
   cy.wait( '@getPages' ).its( 'response.statusCode' ).should( 'eq', 200 );
   cy.wait( '@getPosts' ).its( 'response.statusCode' ).should( 'eq', 200 );
} );
```

I've tried increasing the length of time the intercept command waits, but still the request never comes through.

Any ideas why this would be working locally, but not up in a CircleCI build? I've been pulling my hair out for a few days now, trying everything I could think of.

**Localhost:**
[image]

**CircleCI Build:**
[image]

Comment: did you end up finding a solution to this?

Comment: @ege I believe I did. The solution was specific to this use case. Within WordPress the permalinks needed to be set to "pretty permalinks" (Post name). So in this instance, in the CircleCI job the WordPress option `permalink_structure` had to be set to `/%postname%/` , otherwise the REST endpoints didn't work which is why the intercept wasn't caught.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, I was checking for the endpoints `/wp-json/` which require pretty permalinks. In a fresh install of WordPress the default permalink structure makes the REST endpoints accessible at `?rest_route=/`. Updating them to pretty permalinks got my Cypress tests working.

So the solution was, in the CircleCI build, set the WordPress option `permalink_structure`  to `/%postname%/` during the site installation.